# Arrow disappears as soon as overflow:auto element is added to other div

Tags: html, css

Indicating arrow in a box disappears as soon as I add overflow:auto element to other div. Following is the code:

**CSS:**

```
<style>
.arrow_box {
position: relative;
background: #FFF;
box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
width:500px;
border:0px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
bottom: 100%;
left: 73%;
content: " ";
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
}
.arrow_box:after {
border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
border-bottom-color: #FFF;
border-width: 15px;
margin-left: -15px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
border-bottom-color: #dadee0;
border-width: 18px;
margin-left: -18px;
}
#livecart{max-height:500px;overflow-y:auto;} //Without overflow it works fine
#inicart{top:0px;}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='inicart'>
<div id='livecart' class='arrow_box'>
...
...
...
</div>
</div>
```

Livecart div is shown on hover event & if its height crosses max-height element, scrollbar should come into picture, that's a necessity. But that in turn makes arrow disappears from the screen.
Any idea why this is happening? And any turnarounds for this particular problem?

**Here's jsfiddle link**
http://jsfiddle.net/nNJSy/2/

You can try removing overflow:auto from '#livecart' & see the arrow will appear.

Comment: There is not enough information for us to diagnose the problem. A live demo would greatly aid our ability to help in your situation

Comment: I've added jsfiddle in my question. You can go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `overflow:auto` will make the element try to add scrollbars to accommodate any width/height that is not available in the width/height. Meaning anything outside of the visible area can be seen by scrolling.

The behavior however does not effect pseudo elements, thus scrollbars are not added to the parent.

In order for the pseudo element arrow to be seen, you must use `overflow:visible` on the parent, `#livecart`, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/nNJSy/3/)

If you must have `overflow:auto` (say the element has content) then you need to make room for the arrow within the element by using padding, in this case adding `padding-top:30px` [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/nNJSy/4/)

To see the effect of each type of overflow, [check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/NFxLP/)

Comment: Applying padding property adds another 30px area to the right & top side of the box. So ultimately it looks like arrow box inside a box. Don't know why it's coming that way, let me play with it a little.

Comment: @ShanilSoni That's because it's exactly what it's doing, it's adding more space to the top of the block. It's the only way to have `overflow-auto` with the arrow on top though...

Comment: Ohh, thanks anyway for helping in this, my requirement doesn't suit CSS, I guess :(